# Unable to locate element using xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver

Am very new to Selenium just learnt few things and trying to automate.Unable to locate an element in Selenium webdriver for the below one:

```
<div class="navBg withSubMenu">
  <table id="topnav" class="navTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="-moz-user-select: none; cursor: default;">
     <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td class="logoCell navCell" valign="top">
           <td class="navItem navCell relative selected">
           <td class="navItem navCell relative notSelected">
               <a class="content tasks" href="/tasks/otasklist.do">
                  <div class="label" style="z-index:155; ">TASKS</div>
                  <div class="img"> </div>
               </a>
           </td>
           <td class="navItem navCell relative notSelected">
               <a class="content reports" href="/reports/reports.do">
           </td>
           <td class="navItem navCell relative notSelected">
           <td class="menuCell navCell" valign="top">
        </tr>
     <tr class="secondLevelRow">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have written code like

```
driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[Contains(@class,'content tasks')]")).click();
```

Anyone please help me.

And also please suggest some sites or links to learn more about locators especially xpath. I tried  few but not getting it in depth.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<a class="content tasks" href="/tasks/otasklist.do">

driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='content tasks']")).click();
```

Answer (score 3):

Start `contains` with a lower case `c`:

```
driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'content tasks')]")).click();
```

Comment: And also please suggest some sites or links to learn more about locators especially xpath. I tried few but not getting it in depth.

Comment: @Harish, please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.

Comment: I like [**XML Path Language (XPath)**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/).   It's the official reference, and it's very approachable too.   See, for example, the examples listed in [2 Location Paths](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths).